# Setting em-dashes with hair spaces

Tags: spacing, punctuation

Em-dashes — when used to separate parenthetical clauses — are often used without any spacing, but I rather prefer them with a hair (or perhaps thin) space on either side.

The ‘obvious’ way to do this is probably to write `A\,---\,B` rather than `A---B` (no spaces) or `A --- B` (unfortunately large spaces). However, this does not allow line breaks around the dash, should they be needed.

The best solution I've been able to come up with is this:

```
\newcommand{\mdash}
           {\discretionary{}{}{\kern 0.1em}---\discretionary{}{}{\kern 0.1em}}
```

It looks like that works, but:

- Does this look like good practice?
- Is there a standard way to do this?
- Is there any way to, say, call this command `----` rather than `\mdash{}`?

Comment: You can call it `\frenchdash` since it's the typographical norm in French…

Comment: @Bernard https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiret appears to suggest a full-width space around an em-dash, as well as a prohibition on line breaks…

Comment: Your own solution is OK. If you like the result, do it. Or, if you always use a particular font, you might edit that font (in FontForge) so that its ordinary emdash looks like you want, with space on either side. That's what I do.

Comment: @tjollans: More  precisely: a normal space *before* an opening emdash and a *thin unbreakable* space *after*, and the symmetric layout for a closing emdash (cf Jacques André, *Petites leçons de typographie*, p.32 — I suppose you read French :o)

Comment: Note that it is an **e**mdash and not an mdash. An em is a printer's measure, as marked on editors' rulers. I'm pretty convinced I do it all wrong as I always write ` --- blah --- `. So I wouldn't advise what I do, as it is probably wrong.

Comment: To answer the third question: yes, this is possible. Even if you don't want or are not permitted to edit the original font. But you probably don't want to go this route: you need to create customised TFM/VF files for this and you'd need to give up slots in your encoding for it (e.g. T1). You can, but I certainly wouldn't.

Comment: take a look at how `ltugboat.cls` defines `\Dash`.  we've been using it for years, and have had no line-breaking problems (although i seem to remember that we chose to allow breaks only *after* the dash).

Comment: Those aren't hair spaces.  Those are thin spaces.  Hair spaces are even more narrow, but there's no pre-defined shortcut for hair spaces in Latex.

Comment: If you want hair spaces and you're using XeTeX or LuaTeX, you can use the [hair space unicode encoding](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+200A): `\newcommand{\mdash}{\symbol{"200A}---\symbol{"200A}}`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

tugboat has been setting em-dashes with thin spaces for years.  (the editors are
*not* fond of the dash nearly crashing into whatever is on either side.)

here is a somewhat simplified version of the tugboat definitions.
Observe that it wipes out preceding and following spaces so results are uniform.

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\thinskip}{\hskip 0.16667em\relax}
\def\emdash{---}
\def\d@sh#1#2{\unskip#1\thinskip#2\thinskip\ignorespaces}
\def\Dash{\d@sh\nobreak\emdash}
\def\Ldash{\d@sh\empty{\hbox{\emdash}\nobreak}}
\def\Rdash{\d@sh\nobreak\emdash}
```

a line break is permissible on either side of the basic `\Dash`.  (the use of
`\thinskip` with `\hskip` rather than `\thinspace` is what allows this.)

if a line break should be permitted on only the right or left of the dash,
`\Rdash` and `\Ldash` are provided to accommodate that.

Comment: Thanks, though it looks like \Dash and \Rdash are identical in this definition. That should be easily fixed by changing \Dash to `\def\Dash{\d@sh\empty\emdash}`

Comment: it's a fact that in tugboat `\Dash` and `\Rdash` are identical.  ordinarily (for tugboat, anyhow) it's not really desirable to have a "following" dash break to a new line; the exception is when the first of paired em-dashes encloses a parenthetical comment, and then a break is allowed intentionally (hence the `\Ldash`).

Comment: How do you use it? `I believe\Ldash but may be wrong\Rdash like this?`

Comment: @Clément -- The example you show is indeed how it's used, and a break is allowed *before* but not *after* the `\Ldash`.  That is rare, more frequent in "British" prose that U.S.; it's entirely stylistic, but in the proper context, necessary.

Answer (score 7):

First off I need to note this method works *only* with pdfTeX (≥1.40).

I used the microtype package as such:

```latex
\usepackage[activate=false,kerning]{microtype}
\SetExtraKerning[unit=character]{encoding=*}{\textemdash={100,100}}
```

As far as I can tell, this is pretty much the sort of thing microtype kerning is designed for, and if nothing else has the advantage that you can still just type `---`.

This adds space (but not *a* space), equal to a tenth of the dash itself, to the left and right (this is half a 'thin space'). The unit is actually a thousandth of what is assigned to `unit`; `unit=1em` would make the unit 0.001em.

This package adds some very nice automatic features if you omit the `activate=false` as well.

A documented (extremely minor in my view) limitation of microtype kerning is that the word following the dash will not be automatically hyphenated—but you can still insert a manual breakpoint. I haven't tested this.

I don't believe this changes the breaking behaviour immediately before or after the dash; I've certainly confirmed that it will still break immediately after, and it still does this in preference to hyphenating a word.

Comment: I really like this solution, but microtype gives me a warning: "`kerning codes list \`temp.tex/162' will(microtype) override list \`empty' for (microtype) font \`T1////'`", I am not sure what to make of it.